# Segmentation fault when dealing with connection object

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, delete-operator, libpqxx

I have bunch of methods:

```
bool PGConnection::connect() {
    try
    {
        conn = new pqxx::connection(
                            "user=temp "
                            "host=xxxx "
                            "password=xx "
                            "dbname=temp");
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Disconnect from db
bool PGConnection::disconnect() {
        if ( conn->is_open()) {
            std::cout<<"try disconnect"<<std::endl;
            conn->disconnect();
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

PGConnection::~PGConnection() {
    if ( conn != NULL) {
        delete conn;
   }
}
```

When disconnect or class destructor is called, it results in segmantation fault. (When i comment out disconnect part below it happens when destructor is called.)

```
int main () {
 PGConnection pgConn("xxx","xxx");
 pgConn.connect();
 pgConn.disconnect();
 return 0;
 }
```

[gdb with disconnect() called](http://pastebin.com/8PqdYw93):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ba4852 in pqxx::connection_base::is_open() const () from /usr/lib/libpqxx-3.1.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ba4852 in pqxx::connection_base::is_open() const () from /usr/lib/libpqxx-3.1.so
#1  0x00000000004019d3 in PGConnection::disconnect (this=0x7fffffffe600) at pgconnection.cpp:42
#2  0x000000000040269e in main () at main.cpp:8
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x000000000040269e in main () at main.cpp:8
8       pgConn.disconnect();
(gdb) print pgConn
$1 = {conn = 0x3}
```

[gdb with out calling disconnect](http://pastebin.com/MqszDu0V):

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ba5fdb in pqxx::connection_base::close() () from /usr/lib/libpqxx-3.1.so
#1  0x0000000000401d3e in pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>::~basic_connection (this=0x3,
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/pqxx/basic_connection.hxx:74
#2  0x0000000000401a3d in PGConnection::~PGConnection (this=0x7fffffffe600, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at pgconnection.cpp:57
#3  0x00000000004026a3 in main () at main.cpp:11
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0000000000401a3d in PGConnection::~PGConnection (this=0x7fffffffe600, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at pgconnection.cpp:57
57          delete conn;
(gdb) print conn
$1 = (pqxx::connection *) 0x3
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the constructor for `PGConnection`.  In particular, the constructor should always set `conn=NULL`.

I'd also recommend that the line that currently says

```
    if ( conn->is_open()) {
```

Should instead be

```
    if (conn && conn->is_open()) {
```

I strongly suspect that your `conn` member is not being properly initialized.

Better still would be to redesign the class so that you eliminate the use of `new` and `delete` entirely if you can.  If you do so, it would be a much better way of solving the problem.  There's not likely to be much reason for `PGConnection` to exist unless it's about to connect to something, so the constructor could also contain the code to instantiate a `pqxx::connection`.

Comment: Heh. How did i missed that. Great catch! I didn't assign it to NULL in the constructor.